# Building an ad-hoc mesh network with batman-adv

Tags: networking

I am attempting to set up an ad-hoc wireless mesh network with a few RPis as part of a project at University this summer. I have looked around at a number of ways of doing this, there doesn't seem to be a clear winner however I found batman-adv, and this post on reddit on how to set it up [Batman-adv configuration](https://www.reddit.com/r/darknetplan/comments/68s6jp/how_to_configure_batmanadv_on_the_raspberry_pi_3/).  I have attempted to get this to work with a simple setup of 2x RPi Bs, one connected to the internet via ethernet, and the other not connected. Both pis have a wifi dongle that have previously connected to wifi networks successfully.

I followed the commands in the reddit post, all worked as planned until I got to testing the network was actually up and running. The command 
`sudo batctl o`
returns nothing to stdout, thus I assume it cannot see the other pi. However a ping to the other pi does work.
`sudo ping 172.27.0.1`
 As one of the pis has no internet connection I assume that there must be at least some sort of communication, unless the ping is not going where I think it is.

A ping to the MAC address however does not work 
`sudo batctl ping b8:27:eb:7e:08:f0` 
i get `destination host unreachable`

Can anyone suggest something that I have missed? Is there some prerequisite that I have overlooked? I have followed the reddit post line by line nothing more nothing less.